# Is there any way to get the class name of an element on click with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, markup, classname

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to get the `class name` of some element when the user clicks on the element with `selenium`.

The way this would work is

1. The user opens a webpage with selenium
2. The user clicks on an element in the opened browser
3. the respective class name of the element is returned to the user

I know we can search for elements in a webpage with their ids or classes using `driver.find_element_by_id` or `driver.find_element_by_xpath` but can we do the reverse with selenium?

Comment: Getattribute should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned user clicks on an element using selenium.
In that case, I would assume you already know the element to click on.

And therefore can use `element.getAttribute("class")` to get the class Name of the object.